# Custom UIView from XIB loading with huge scale for subviews

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got an issue with a custom UIView implementation. What I am trying to do is animate a UICollectionViewCell, and creating a new view after the cell scales and 'flips' on the other side. (Think of the UICollectionViewCells as cards).

I successfully manage to achieve the desired animation. However, when I create a view in code from the XIB file, the constraints seem to be applied but everything is blown up in size. I set the minimum font scale for the labels to 0.2, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the view designed in IB:

[View designed in IB with constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVdEy.png)

Now here is what I get when the animation proceeds to add a new CardBackView to the cell's view:

[The horrendous result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O08Sj.png)

This is the code that does the animation and adds the card back view:

```
// now flip card and show other side of card
            UIView.transitionWithView(cell, duration: duration, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .TransitionFlipFromRight, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: { () -> Void in

                let cardBackView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardBackView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! CardBackView
                cardBackView.frame = cell.bounds
                cardBackView.titleLabel.text = movie.title
                cardBackView.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cardBackView.overviewLabel.text = movie.overview
                cardBackView.backgroundColor = UISettings.TabBarColor
                cell.addSubview(cardBackView)

                }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding your CardBackView to your Cell it assumes that your translating your autoresizing mask into constraints, so it might behave weirdly. To fix this you need to create constraints for your CardBackView and add them to your Cell (it's parent).

If your CardBackView should use the same size as your Cell, something like this should work:

```
cardBackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardBackView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardBackView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardBackView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardBackView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```